# Get Year of Previous Month (For Jan 1st)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently building a YTD report in SSRS. I'm looking to edit the default "FROM" date in a calendar selection.

I'm looking to retrieve January 1st of the previous months year. For example:

(If it's Feb 16th, 2016 .. the result should be **1/1/2016**

If it's Jan 10th, 2016 .. the result should be **1/1/2015**)

I built this to retrieve the current year for jan 1st, but it causes issues if we're in January because I need it to retrieve the year of the previous month (in that case it would be 2015, not 2016).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like this? 
    Year(DateAdd(m,-1,Parameter!myParameter.Value))

Comment: Please google and learn about Expressions in SSRS.   You can write an expression for the default value of your parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), 1))
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment I've created this expression. It is not tested but should work.

```
=IIF(Today.Month>1,
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), 1)),
DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), 1))
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tested this in my from date parameter but the result was 12/1/2015. I'm looking at finding 1/1/2015 based on the previous month. Thanks!

Comment: Your changes makes it so I see 1/1/2015 like it should in Jan, however when I change my system clock to Feb, I still see 1/1/2015. When this report is reading a feb system time, it should spit out 1/1/2016 as the previous months year would now become 2016.

Comment: Try with harcoded dates instead of change your system date. i.e. `CDate("2016-02-15")`. Replace `Today` by the date you want to test.

Comment: I actually found a problem. I thought my report was being hosted locally on my machine, but it's actually on a server. That means my tests on your queries were bad because my system time wasn't changing (as it was the servers system time that matters).

I can't change my servers system time because of existing reports/tasks/etc -- is there a way I can test your method artificially?

Comment: Check my previous comment. Replace `Today` by  `CDate("2016-02-15")`.

Comment: Replacing [Today] with CDate("2016-02-15") changed the value from 1/1/2015 to 12/1/2015. I wonder why it's not displaying as 1/1/2016.

Comment: Check you have replaced all `Today` occurrences.

Comment: I replaced my expression with:

=IIF(CDate("2016-02-15").Month>1,
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,DateSerial(Year(CDate("2016-02-15")), Month(CDate("2016-02-15")), 1)),
DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,DateSerial(Year(CDate("2016-02-15")), Month(CDate("2016-02-15")), 1))
)

It is showing a date of 1/1/2016. Since the CDate is referencing Feb, that means it accurately displayed 1/1/2016. When it's set to "today", it displays 1/1/2015 like it should.


Thanks man, you're the best!

Comment: Replace `IIF(Today.Month>1` by `=IIF(CDate("2016-02-15").Month>1` too

Answer (score 0):

We want to use Date Serial which has the forma
=DateSerial(YYYY,MM,DD)
The Month is always January
The day is always the first
If the month is January, it's last year.  Otherwise, it's this year.
So, assuming we have an SSRS report with a parameter called Date , we can create a new field for your January date as follows:

```
=iif(Month(Parameters!Date.Value)=1, 
    dateserial(Year(Parameters!Date.Value)-1,1,1),
    dateserial(Year(Parameters!Date.Value),1,1))
```

if you want to do this in the query with T-SQL (version 2012) or later:

```
case when month(@DATE) = 1 
    then DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DATE)-1,1,1)
    else DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DATE),1,1) 
 end
```

OR, in earlier versions

```
  CASE WHEN MONTH(@DATE) = 1 
        THEN CAST(CAST((YEAR(@DATE)-1)*10000 + 101 AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE) 
        ELSE CAST(CAST((YEAR(@DATE)*10000+ 101) AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE) 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(cast(year(dateadd(mm, -1,getdate())) as varchar)+'-01-01' as date)
```

replace getdate() with which ever field you're basing this calculation on.

for testing:

```
select cast(cast(year(dateadd(mm, -1,'2015-01-22')) as varchar)+'-01-01' as date)
select cast(cast(year(dateadd(mm, -1,'2016-02-01')) as varchar)+'-01-01' as date)
select cast(cast(year(dateadd(mm, -1,'2015-12-12')) as varchar)+'-01-01' as date)
```